# I don't know who my dad is but I have DNA paternal matches

Tags: autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

I have DNA matches on Ancestry.com but none high enough to be my father.  However, all the matches point to a common name as our ancestor.

The highest match is 959 over 42 but the person it matches to is 20 years older then me and I think he has to be an uncle. He is not in good shape and cannot answer our questions. Can he be an uncle?

His daughter comes out as a first cousin as does another person related to them.  My third cousin match is also related to what I think is the common ancestor.  The first cousins are around my age and so is the third cousin - just a few years younger then me.

What does it mean?  The family of the names we think we share used to live in the neighborhood I was born in.

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy, Sabina.  I did a light edit on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your highest match is 959 cM.  He is not your uncle.  That requires cM in the range of 1349-2175.  Using the [Shared cM Project](https://thegeneticgenealogist.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Relationship_Chart_FINAL_August_2017.jpg) data.

He could be your:

- Half uncle.  Your biological dad would be his half brother.
- Great uncle.  While most great uncles would be 40+ years older, not 20, this doesn't rule it out.  This means he would be the full brother of one of your bio dad's parents.
- First cousin.  Your dad and one of your match's parents are full siblings. Your match's daughter would be your first cousin once removed.

You need more data.  Either paper trail or DNA.  This is a very close match and I hope it brings you nearer to the answer you're looking for.